# Is it possible to draw out USD from ATMs in Lilongwe, Malawi?

Tags: money, africa, malawi

I will be travelling through Malawi over New years and a lot of the activities I have planned need payment in USD, and I don't want to carry the full amount in cash for my entire trip.

So is it possible for me to replenish my funds in Lilongwe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATMs will only dispense cash in the local currency, but you might be able to get USD from a money changer because USD is quite popular.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information or is it personal experience?

Comment: Personal experience